# Separating layers based on labels

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling

I have the following data set [Data](https://mega.nz/file/U4kEVDJR#J5Nf4Tn9LAwJlLcUAYQqBzSq3NHtVHVy0qDQ0MSn1hA). There are 3 different kinds of labels: "Baja", "Media", "Alta".

Each label is assigned to a polygon.

Is there any way to separate the layer in three different layers depending on what label they are in?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is splitting the layer using the function `Split vector layer`
[image]

You then select the attribute field of your choice for classifying the features
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate layer and filter features in it using:

`"CLASIFICAC" = 'ALTA'`

Screen cast:
https://ibb.co/THrgpJn